# Dropdown lists in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dropdown, html-lists

I am trying to make a price calculator with the following calculation:

The final price = the original price (1 - percentage)  (100 - special) /100

I got the getting price part down, the getting the special down, but when it comes down to the percentage (its a percentage established by choosing a color on a droplist) I dont understand how to get the list on html to work with the Model in C#.

I am very new to ASP.NET and coding in general and I simply dont understand how this works.

In the Index.cshtml section of the program I typed the list as such:

```
<label asp-for="Color">The color of tag:</label>
<select name="colors" id="color">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to give each color a percentage so that the calculations that are supposed to go on the Model work properly but I don't know how to do this.
I got advised by my instructor to add this to the Model:

```
public string Color {get; set;}
```

But don't really know to what end. I don't know if Im overthinking things or simply I am not experienced enough. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to simply get the value of the droplist , set the option value:

```
<select class="colors" id="color">
<option value=0.1 style="background-color:red;">Red</option>
<option value=0.2 style="background-color:orange;">Orange</option>
<option value=0.3 style="background-color:yellow;">Yellow</option>
<option value=0.4 style="background-color:green;">Green</option>
</select>
```

Then you can get the value through $("#color").val().

If you mean to get the value from model and pass it to the back-end , here is code sample:

index.cshtml

```
...
<select class="colors" id="color">
    <option value=0 style="background-color:none;">Select the percentage</option>
</select>
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> <!-- Including jQuery library -->
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        InitDrop();
        $('#color').change(function () {
            GetRecordsList();
        });
    })

    function InitDrop() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SelectList/GetRecords',
            type: 'Get',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                forPer: $("#color").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#color").append('<option value=' + item.percentage + ' style="background-color:' + item.color + ';"' + '>' + item.color + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function GetRecordsList() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SelectList/GetRecords',
            type: 'Get',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                forPer: $("#color").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    //Your own function here
                });
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Test.cs ---this is under your Model folder, model should include the properties you need.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplicationPercentage.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public double percentage { get; set; }
        public string? color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SelectListController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplicationPercentage.Models;

namespace WebApplicationPercentage.Controllers
{
    public class SelectListController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetRecords(double forPer)
        {
            // Replace with your actual data retrieval logic from the database
            List<Test> mockData = new List<Test>();
            Test p1 = new Test();
            p1.percentage = 0.1;
            p1.color = "red";
            Test p2 = new Test();
            p2.percentage = 0.2;
            p2.color = "orange";
            Test p3 = new Test();
            p3.percentage = 0.3;
            p3.color = "yellow";
            mockData.Add(p1);
            mockData.Add(p2);
            mockData.Add(p3);

            var List = new List<Test>();
            Console.WriteLine(forPer);
            if (forPer == 0)
            {
                List = mockData;
            }
            else
            {
                List = mockData.Where(a => a.percentage == forPer).ToList();
            }
            return Json(List);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the page

[image: percentage list]

And you can see the value from back-end

[image: log]